# tableView cellForRow autoreleases my object

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, uitableview

I have created an object like this :

```
NSDictionary *listProfils;

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *listProfils;

...

@synthetize listProfils
```

Later in the code I do set my object within the **viewDidLoad** method, then make a count within the method **tableView:tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:**

The problem is that when the program read the method **tableView:tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:** , my object is already released whereas it was not in the previous method.

Does anyone know what is the problem here and why my object is released ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: when you create the object, are you creating it with +1 retain count?

Comment: First, it looks like synthesize is misspelled...maybe just a typo when posting your question, but figured I'd let you know in case it's causing problems in your code :)

Comment: Please post the actual code where you create and assign the listProfils object.  There's nothing here to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough of your code code to tell for sure what is wrong, but I'll make a guess. You probably did something like

```
listProfils = [NSDictionary dictionaryWith... //etc.];
```

and since that returns an autoreleased dictionary, which is not retained by the ivar, the dictionary will be released after a while. Better use a property reference:

```
self.listProfils = [NSDictionary dictionaryWith... //etc.];
```

That will take care of retaining the dictionary you just created and autorelease will take care of releasing the local reference.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem. Thank you very much. I will have a deeper look at iVAR and self. thanks ;)

Comment: `self`is just the `id` that represents the receiver of the method. The syntax `myProperty` accesses an ivar, just like `self->myProperty`, while `self.myPoperty` access the ivar through the methods typically called `myProperty`and `setMyProperty:`, generated by `@synthesize`-ing the property.